# Updating an XML with specific elements it's missing from a good XML

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a "good" XML file with the required element and a "bad" XML file with the specific element missing. Here are the good and a couple of bad XML files.

good.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<level1>
<level2>
<level3>
<l3v1>hello</l3v1>
<l3v2>world</l3v2>
</level3>
</level2>
</level1>
```

bad1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<level1>
<level2>
<level4>
<l4v1>inconsequential</l4v1>
</level4>
</level2>
</level1>
```

bad2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<level1>
<level2>
<level3>
<l3v3>inconsequential also</l3v3>
</level3>
</level2>
</level1>
```

I would like to read good.xml and see if bad1.xml, bad2.xml have level3/l3v1, level3/l3v2.. If not, add these elements.

Code I have so far is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import functools

def update_configxml(element_name: str,bad_xml: str, good_xml: str):
  tree = ET.parse(good_xml) #Correct XML
  root = tree.getroot()
  for item in root.findall(element_name): #element of interest
    print(item.tag)

  t2 = ET.parse(bad_xml) #Incorrect XML
  r2 = t2.getroot()

  try:
    if r2.findall(element_name) == []:
      print ("{} Not found.\nAppending...".format(item.tag))
      #r2.append(item) #This does not create level3 under level2, but puts level3 under level1
      parent_str = functools.reduce(lambda q,r: str(q)+"/"+str(r), element_name.split('/')[0:-1])
      parent = r2.find(parent_str)
      if parent is None:
        parent = ET.SubElement(r2,parent_str)
        item = ET.SubElement(parent,item)
      else:
        item = ET.SubElement(parent,item)
    else:
      print ("{} found".format(item.tag))
  except UnboundLocalError as notfound:
    print(notfound)
    print("The good config also does not seem to have the required tag")

  print(ET.tostring(r2, encoding='utf8').decode('utf8'))



if __name__ == '__main__':
  element = './level2/level3' #Element to add to bad XML files
  update_configxml(element,'bad1.xml','good.xml')
```

But I get:

```
(base) C:\Users\myneni\jenkins>python3 update_xml_test.py
level3
level3 Not found.
Appending...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update_xml_test.py", line 35, in <module>
    update_configxml(element,'bad1.xml','good.xml')
  File "update_xml_test.py", line 29, in update_configxml
    print(ET.tostring(r2, encoding='utf8').decode('utf8'))
  File "C:\Python36\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1135, in tostring
    short_empty_elements=short_empty_elements)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 773, in write
    qnames, namespaces = _namespaces(self._root, default_namespace)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 885, in _namespaces
    _raise_serialization_error(tag)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1057, in _raise_serialization_error
    "cannot serialize %r (type %s)" % (text, type(text).__name__)
TypeError: cannot serialize <Element 'level3' at 0x0000021616D81098> (type Element)
```

How do I copy the parent tree and add it to the bad.xml file to include the element of interest?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your solution I noticed an error in `item = ET.SubElement(parent, item)`:
*item* parameter should be the **name** of the created element (a **string**),
whereas you passed an **Element**.

Other doubtful point is whether in *ElementTree* one element can be put in multiple
trees. Note that you attempt to **copy** entire subtree and I doubt whether such
combination is allowed. Maybe you should rather use a *deepcopy* instead and
*append* the created copy to the bad tree.

Instead of correcting your solution, I came up with another, based on *lxml*.
This module has more useful functions and my solution (in my opinion) is more
modular, readable and easier to maintain.

Start with import:

```
from lxml import etree
```

Then create 2 functions:

1. The first function creates missing elements in the given *tree*, along
   the given *xpath*:

   ```
   def createElem(tree: etree._ElementTree, xpath: str):
       nodes = tree.xpath(xpath)
       if nodes:         # Target element exists
           pass  # print(f'Target element exists.')
       else:
           # Drop empty string before 1st "/" and the root node name
           parts = xpath.split('/')[2:]
           p = tree.getroot()  # Start scanning from the root
           for part in parts:
               nodes = p.xpath(part)  # Attempt to descend 1 level
               if nodes:  # Child element exists
                   # print(f'Element {part} exists.')
                   p = nodes[0]
               else:  # No such child element
                   n = etree.SubElement(p, part)  # Create child
                   # print(f'Element {part} created.')
                   p = n      # Parent for the next step
   ```
2. The second function (a reworked version of your function) reads both XML files,
   adds missing elements to the bad tree and returns it.

   ```
   def update_configxml(element_name: str, bad_xml: str, good_xml: str) -> etree._ElementTree:
       parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
       tree = etree.parse(good_xml, parser)  # Read good XML
       root = tree.getroot()
       t2 = etree.parse(bad_xml, parser)     # Read bad XML
       basePath = '/' + root.tag + element_name[1:]
       for it in tree.iter():
           pth = tree.getpath(it)
           if pth.startswith(basePath):
               # print(f'Check for: {it.tag:6}  {pth}')
               createElem(t2, pth)
       return t2
   ```

Compared to your code, I changed the signature of this function (it returns the updated tree),
in order to allow to do something with it (not only print).

I called the above function:

```
result = update_configxml('./level2/level3', 'bad1.xml', 'good.xml')
```

and printed its content:

```
print(etree.tostring(result, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))
```

getting:

```
<level1>
  <level2>
    <level4>
      <l4v1>inconsequential</l4v1>
    </level4>
    <level3>
      <l3v1/>
      <l3v2/>
    </level3>
  </level2>
</level1>
```

As you can see, *level3* and its children have been added.

A note about *update_configxml* function: I added there a parser
with *remove_blank_text* option, to get the final printout with proper indentation.
To see the difference:

- change reading of bad XML to just `t2 = etree.parse(bad_xml)`,
- run the modified code and
- print the result (like I did).